# Writing an equation on two lines and adjusting the second line to the center

Tags: equations, alignment

I am trying to split my equation into two lines. I want to adjust the second line to the center instead of having it at the left end of the equation.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x(k+3) = A[A^2x(k+1) + ABu(k) + AFd(k) + Af + Bu(k+1) + Fd(k+1) + f] + Bu(k+2) \\
+ Fd(k+2) + f
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: For such aligning is intended `gather` environment, defined in the `amsmath` package: `\begin{gather*}
x(k+3) = A[A^2x(k+1) + ABu(k) + AFd(k) + Af + Bu(k+1) + Fd(k+1) + f] + Bu(k+2) \\
+ Fd(k+2) + f
\end{gather*}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably interested in `gather*` rather than `aligned`, although a more common approach is to use `align*` with the appropriate alignment markers `&` and spacing correction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  x(k + 3) &= A \bigl[ A^2 x(k + 1) + A B u(k) + A F d(k) + A f + B u(k + 1) + F d(k + 1) + f \bigr] + B u(k + 2) \\
           &\phantom{{}={}} + F d(k + 2) + f
\end{align*}

\begin{gather*}
  x(k + 3) = A \bigl[ A^2 x(k + 1) + A B u(k) + A F d(k) + A f + B u(k + 1) + F d(k + 1) + f \bigr] + B u(k + 2) \\
    {} + F d(k + 2) + f
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `{}` in the second line of `gather*` to achieve the appropriate spacing around the binary operator `+`.